# XPages file download control issue

Tags: xpages

I have a file download control on custom control and this custom cotrol is there in xpage. Now when I click on attachment link in file download control, i get a prompt "Do you want to open or save this file". If i click on cancel/open/save... the xpage gets un responsive and no button works (I have edit and close button on page).

Comment: Really not a lot to go on here. I'd recommend to create a small sample and paste the XSP code.

Comment: Please add more info such as a code sample, which browser you are using and which version of that browser you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Domino and which browser are you using. Bear in mind 8.5.2 uses Dojo 1.5 but Internet Explorer 9 only supports Dojo 1.6 onwards.

If this is the problem, partial refreshes will not work anywhere on any XPage. to overcome it you should be able override the IE version.